# VUE: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am following a vue tutorial. Below is the function to implement character limit on a text area ,

```
<form action="" class="create-twoot" @submit.prevent="createnewTwoot">
   <label for="new-twoot">New Twoot</label>
   <p>{{char_limit}}/180</p>
   <textarea name="" id="new-twoot" cols="30" rows="4" v-model="newTwootcontent"></textarea>
   <br/>
   <label for="newTwootType">Twoot Type</label>
   <select name="TwootType" id="newTwootType" v-model="twootType">
      <option :value="option.name" v-for="(option,index)  in twootTypes" :key="index">
         {{option.value}}
      </option>
   </select>
   <br/>
   <button>Tweet</button>
</form>
```

**JS CODE**

```
export default {
  name: 'Userprofile',
  newTwootcontent: '',
  twootType: 'instant',
  
    computed:{
    char_limit(){
      return this.newTwootcontent.length;
    },
    fullname(){
      return `${this.users.fname} ${this.users.lname}`;
    }
  },
}
```

Everything else is working fine but this `char_limit` is giving below error

(i did not post data , methods etc since these were working fine )

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Proxy.char_limit (Userprofile.vue?5045:102)
```

can someone advise me what's the issue with code

Comment: first check out the basics, Data and Methods: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i have added methods and data and it was working find , pls let me know if i should post that code as well

Comment: post code as-is, else as-is you're defining what should be in data on the vue instance which is wrong, hence the error

Comment: @LawrenceCherone as per answer by Amaarrockz i defined newTwootcontent inside data  and it solved the issue  , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the variables inside the data section like

```
export default {
  name: 'Userprofile',
  data() {
    return {
      newTwootcontent: '',
      twootType: 'instant',
    };
  }
    computed:{
    char_limit(){
      return this.newTwootcontent.length;
    },
    fullname(){
      return `${this.users.fname} ${this.users.lname}`;
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: sure in few minutes it will allow to accept , just one clarification all the properties need to be defined inside data ? pls confirm

Comment: Yes all the variables should be defined in data

Comment: Only then they can be accessed using 'this' operator. Also do not confuse computed and methods with the data variables since they can also be accessed using 'this' operator